# Coupon updates for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm currently making a small app for a business that just wants users to be able to view their coupons on their app instead of the fliers.

Since I am new at iPhone development I was just wondering how to do this. Right now I just have pictures of the coupons that are in the project. If I want to add new coupons however I would have to change the source code and then change the version.

Will I have to update the application every time I add new coupons? Or is there a way I can dynamically do it without the user having to update the application.

Thanks for any help/ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to store and update your coupons in the cloud (your own server, etc.) and define a RESTful interface to it. Then your app will download the up-to-date list of (active) coupons when the user opens it. You might want to use a library such as [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) to avoid having to write the low-level Objective-C http code.

Answer (score 2):

The user would be forced to update the app every time you add new coupons.

If you had the coupon images on a server, and load the coupons from there every time the app loads, then the user wouldn't need to update the app. You could simply keep putting more coupon images into your server.

Answer (score 1):

Or an easy way to implement this would be to create a UIWebView and point it to a website where you can constantly loop the coupon images and the user would never know that they were looking at a webview.